# Dockerized Django backend fails to connect to Postgress

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a Django/Gunicorn/Ngnix/Postgres project deployed in docker containers in a DigitalOcean ubuntu droplet. When running `docker-compose up` I get this error:

```
dev          | Traceback (most recent call last):
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
dev          |     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
dev          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
dev          |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
dev          | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'None'
dev          | 
dev          | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
dev          | 
dev          | Traceback (most recent call last):
dev          |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
dev          |     main()
dev          |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
dev          |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
dev          |     utility.execute()
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
dev          |     django.setup()
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
dev          |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
dev          |     app_config.import_models()
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
dev          |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
dev          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
dev          |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
dev          |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
dev          |     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
dev          |     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 141, in __new__
dev          |     new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
dev          |     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
dev          |     self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
dev          |     return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
dev          |     conn = self.create_connection(alias)
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
dev          |     backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
dev          |   File "/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
dev          |     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
dev          | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'None' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
```

The DB is running ok:

```
2023-11-28 22:01:16.611 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_dev       | 2023-11-28 22:01:16.612 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_dev       | 2023-11-28 22:01:16.612 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_dev       | 2023-11-28 22:01:16.615 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_dev       | 2023-11-28 22:01:16.619 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-28 21:37:26 UTC
db_dev       | 2023-11-28 22:01:16.624 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.22.0
    container_name: webserver
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
      - ./nginx/configs/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - backend

  db_prod:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PROD_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_prod:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_ENGINE: ${POSTGRES_ENGINE}
    # profiles: #TODO: fix  Unsupported config option for services.{service_name}: 'profiles'
    #   - prod
    networks:
      - backend


  db_dev:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_DEV_PORT}:5433"
    volumes:
      - db_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_ENGINE: ${POSTGRES_ENGINE}
    # profiles:
    #   - dev
    networks:
      - backend

  prod:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    volumes:
      - env_prod:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/prod/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_prod
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_prod
    # profiles:
    #   - prod
    networks:
      - backend

  dev:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    volumes:
      - env_dev:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/dev/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_dev
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_dev
    # profiles:
    #   - dev
    networks:
      - backend

  adminer:
    image: dockette/adminer:pgsql
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      UPLOAD: ${ADM_UPLOAD}
    # profiles:
    #   - dev
    #   - prod
    networks:
      - backend

volumes:
  db_prod:
  db_dev:
  env_dev:
  env_prod:

networks:
  backend:
```

start script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
/env/bin/gunicorn --bind :5000 config.wsgi:application --workers 3 --access-logfile $LOG_PATH/gunicorn/access.log --error-logfile $LOG_PATH/gunicorn/error.log --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --log-level debug
```

Only `dev` and `prod` are falling which are the Django backends

DB Settings:

```py
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_ENGINE')),
        'NAME': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB')),
        'USER': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')),
        'PASSWORD': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')),
        'HOST': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')),
        'PORT': str(os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT')),
    }
}
```

Comment: You should share your settings.py because it seems your database config is where the error is coming from

Comment: share the `DATABASES` dictionary in your `settings.py`

Comment: @Mess, DB settings added.

Comment: @B.Mohammad, it seems the most obvious problems is that your environment variables that reference your database connection details are not properly defined. Make sure you have defined them properly in your environment which I assume is in a `.env` file. You have not defined them in your docker compose but simply referencing them. Your error indicates that the environment variables are not properly defined and turning out to be `None`. You might want to print just above the `DATABASES` settings to see if the env variables actually exists.

Comment: @Mess thank you so much, `POSTGRES_ENGINE` was `None`. You may want to right an answer so I can choose it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your images are working properly. You can simply set your environment variables in your docker compose configuration or in a `.env` file. The simple solution (to start off with) is just to define environment variables directly in the docker compose config for `prod` and `dev`.

In this updated docker compose config, the environment variables are explicitly set just to simplify your testing. Also note, you dont really need to set the environment variable `POSTGRES_ENGINE` since you are using postgres anyway. And we are defaulting the ports to 5432. Again you can make changes after you are able to get a working configuration initially.

Your updated docker compose file.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.22.0
    container_name: webserver
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
      - ./nginx/configs/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:ro
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - backend

  db_prod:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_prod
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - db_prod:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: produser
        POSTGRES_DB: proddb
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prodpassword
    networks:
      - backend


  db_dev:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db_dev
    restart: always
   
    volumes:
      - db_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: devuser
        POSTGRES_DB: devdb
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devpassword

    networks:
      - backend

  prod:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5002:5000
    volumes:
      - env_prod:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/prod/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_prod
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_prod
      POSTGRES_DB: proddb
      POSTGRES_USER: produser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prodpassword

    networks:
      - backend

  dev:
    build: ./src
    command: ["./start.sh"]
    container_name: dev
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    volumes:
      - env_dev:/env:delegated
      - .env:/app/.env:ro
      - ./logs/dev/gunicorn/:/var/log/gunicorn/
    depends_on:
      - db_dev
    environment:
      LOG_PATH: /var/log
      POSTGRES_HOST: db_dev
      POSTGRES_DB: devdb
      POSTGRES_USER: devuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devpassword
    # profiles:
    #   - dev
    networks:
      - backend

  adminer:
    image: dockette/adminer:pgsql
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      UPLOAD: ${ADM_UPLOAD}
    # profiles:
```

Also change your `DATABASES` config in settings.py to the following:

```
    import os # place at the top if you have not already.

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
            'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
            'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        }
    }
```